# How can I allocate more memory to a full list using the NEW operator in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, exception, playlist

I'm trying to make a playlist with songs. I am using the List data structure in c++. I want to improve on a function insert(), where if my list is full of 100 songs, I can allocate more memory to the list using the operator NEW. I also have to deallocate existing memory using delete[].

I'm not sure how to create a new list and connect them together.

Here's my List class:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;


template<class ItemType>
class List
{
private:
    static const int CHUNK_SIZE=100;
    ItemType *list;
    int numItems;
    int maxItems;
public:
    // default constructor and destructor
    List()
    {
      numItems = 0;
      maxItems = CHUNK_SIZE;
      list = new ItemType[CHUNK_SIZE];
    }

    ~List()
    {
      delete[] list;
    }
    
    // list member functions
    bool isEmpty()  const 
    {
      return numItems==0;
    }


    int getLength() const 
    { 
      return numItems; 
    }
    bool insert(int pos, const ItemType& item);

    bool remove(int pos);
    
    // clear the list
    // clear can simply set numItems to zero.  The array list may still contain
    // items already inserted into the list, but since numItems is zero, there
    // isn't any way to get at them using getEntry() or setEntry()
    void clear()
    {
      numItems = 0;
    }
    
    // return entry at postion pos
    // throw invalid_argument if pos<1 or pos>getLength()
    ItemType getEntry(int pos) const;
    
    // set entry at postion pos to item
    // throw invalid_argument if pos<1 or pos>getLength()
    // changes whatever is inside the position to that item. swap. 
    void setEntry(int pos, const ItemType& item);
    
};
```

Here's my insert() function:

```
template<class ItemType>
bool List<ItemType>::insert(int pos, const ItemType& item)
{
    bool canAdd;
    
    canAdd = ((pos > 0) && (pos <= numItems + 1) && (numItems < maxItems));
    if (canAdd)
    {
        // first, we have to move everything after our insertion point over one
        // position to make room for our new item.  start at the back of the list.
        // don't forget arrays start at postion zero and our list ADT starts at
        // position 1.
        for(int i=numItems; i>=pos; i--)
            list[i] = list[i-1];
        
        // now put our item at position pos-1
        list[pos-1] = item;
        
        numItems++;
    }

    return canAdd;
}
```

Here's my main() function:

```
int main()
{
    List<string> songs;
    char goAgain = 'y';
    int trackNumber;
    string trackName;
    
    // Insert some songs into our list

    songs.insert(1, "Bohemian Rhaspody");

    songs.insert(2, "The Highway Song");

    songs.insert(3, "In the Loop");

    songs.insert(4, "Lovesong");

    songs.insert(5, "Blow The Whistle");

    songs.remove(1);
      
    cout << "Welcome!  There are " << songs.getLength() << " tracks.\n";
    while (goAgain!='n')
    {
        trackNumber = getTrack();
        try
        {
            trackName = songs.getEntry(trackNumber);
        }
        catch (invalid_argument arg)
        {
            cout << arg.what() << endl;
            trackName = "No Track";
        }
        cout << "Your track name is " << trackName << endl;
        cout << "Go again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> goAgain;
    }
    
    cout << "you're ready to rock!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shown code already uses `new` and `delete`, and moves things around using the assignment operator. That's all that's needed to accomplish the given task, so what, exactly, is unclear to you?

Comment: So If the List reaches the limit of 100, would I have to just declare a new List? How do I redirect all of the inserts() go to into the new list? Do they combine?

Comment: If you have a box that's big enough to hold 100 apples, it's now full, but you build a new box that's now big enough to hold 200 apples: how would you achieve the end result of a single box, containing the same 100 applies, but now having room for another hundred apples? Shouldn't it be obvious that you move the 100 applies to the new box, put it exactly where the old box used to be, then cut up the old box and throw it in the trash?

Comment: A simple approach is to first size your list in its constructor. When you need more space, you create a bigger list and then move all your data into it. The next stage is to do all this book-keeping internally.

Comment: @evanparial The answer to all three of your questions is no. You're not thinking about this in the right way. You have to allocate an new array, copy the items from the old array to the new array and then delete the old array and then set the list to use the new array. All this has to be done in the `insert` function (or in functions it calls). There is no new list, you are modifying an existing list so that it can hold more items.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Since you're (essentially) implementing your "List" as a dynamically allocated array and overallocating (allocating `CHUNKSIZE` elements, even if you don't need that many),  inserting will need to increment `numItems` and, only if that new value exceeds `maxItems`, will need to allocate a larger chunk and copy the previous elements to the newly allocated one, and release the old chunk (and update `maxItems`).